# Turn Lead into GOLD

Tags: wordplay, letters, word-ladder

Can you turn the word LEAD into GOLD in five steps or less? You can change or replace one letter at a time only. The newly formed word must be a legit word in a recognized dictionary. Of course you cannot add or subtract letters, so all new words must have 4 letters. I am sure there are several solutions here.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Three steps/Four words:

> LEAD -> LOAD -> GOAD -> GOLD

Comment: WOW great. Didnt know GOAD as a word.

Comment: I only remembered it because of a word play ladder I created a little bit ago haha

Comment: This is [actually](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/50115/5373) the optimal solution: it's impossible to do better.

Comment: I verified that this is the unique optimal solution - there's nothing else with three steps (in my word list)

Answer (score 11):

- Five steps:

  > LEAD $\rightarrow$ LEND $\rightarrow$ FEND $\rightarrow$ FOND $\rightarrow$ FOLD $\rightarrow$ GOLD
- Four steps:

  > LEAD $\rightarrow$ READ $\rightarrow$ ROAD $\rightarrow$ GOAD $\rightarrow$ GOLD
- @n_palum's [solution](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/50116/5373) in three steps:

  > LEAD $\rightarrow$ LOAD $\rightarrow$ GOAD $\rightarrow$ GOLD

  This is **optimal** because

  > three letters are different between LEAD and GOLD, and we can only change one letter at a time, so we need at least three steps.

Comment: Damn, I had that exact three steps solution in less than one minute from reading the question, but I'm 21 to 22 hours late >_>

Answer (score 7):

Here's one in four steps:

> LEAD
>  MEAD
>  MELD
>  MOLD
>  GOLD

Here's another one in four:

> LEAD
>  HEAD
>  HELD
>  HOLD
>  GOLD