# Lead into IRON! really?

Tags: wordplay, letters, word-ladder

Now that the word LEAD was turned into GOLD in only three steps ([kudos n_palum](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/50116/5373)) can you turn the word LEAD into IRON changing one letter at a time creating new legit 4 letter words (from Dictionary) in 5 steps or less? Again I am sure there are more than a few answers.
And can you do it without using a Proper Noun or name? ( I could not).

Comment: PB - PI - IE - FE done!

Comment: Four letter words Alex

Comment: Has a correct answer been given? If so, please don't forget to $\color{green}{\checkmark \small\text{Accept}}$ it :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to use proper nouns, you could:

> LEAD
>  LEAN
>  LEON
>  IEON
>  IRON

Comment: IEON if that is indeed there then 4 steps are possible.

Comment: According to the internet, it is a spelling of the name that has shown up a fair number of times throughout history.

Answer (score 6):

The best I can do:

> LEAD
> LEAN
> BEAN
> BRAN
> IRAN
> IRON

Comment: I am waiting for someone to do it either 4 steps or without IRAN. We will see

Comment: @DeepakMahulikar It is impossible in 4 steps.

Answer (score 6):

Starting with this list of [4 letter words](http://www.scrabble.org.au/words/fours.htm)

I've found the following three words that are one away from IRON,

> [icon](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/icon_1)
>  [ikon](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/ikon)
>  [tron](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/tron_1)

Unfortunately, the first one only leads back to iron or the 2nd word.

The best I've figured using the 2nd word has 7 steps, and uses some uncommon words.

> lead
>  [leat](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/leat)
>  seat
>  skat
>  [ikat](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/ikat)
>  [ikan](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/ikan)
>  ikon
>  iron

However, using the 3rd word, I've found the following 5 steps, which appears to be optimal.

> lead
>  [tead](http://www.webster-dictionary.org/definition/Tead)
>  [trad](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/trad)
>  trod
>  tron
>  iron

Comment: I was thinking about 'tron' but online it said it's debatable whether tron is a word...

Comment: That's why I included links to the definitions for all of the words.

Comment: Looks like in your third block, you're changing two letters between the 4th and 5th words.

Comment: @TannerSwett good catch, I changed it to my other list, using less common words.

Answer (score 2):

The most optimal solution that I have been able to find is this:

> LEAD -> TEAD -> TRAD -> TROD -> TRON -> IRON

5 steps is the minimal you can do due to the disparity in the letters. Lead is not as close to iron as it is to gold. I think words like Tron or Trad are debatable as to whether or not they constitute as a word. In scrabble they would count but in dictionary means it's up in the air.

Comment: That's one of the possibilities I had as well, but I went with more common words.

Comment: @HerbWolfe If he wants the optimal solution as his answer, that would be it, there's no lower step possibility, it's just less common as you said