# Transforming Colors

Tags: wordplay, letters, word-ladder

Inspired by the [increase of word ladders lately](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/50113/turn-lead-into-gold?noredirect=1&lq=1) I found a fun one.

Transform the color BLUE into PINK.

No proper names.

> Can be 6-7 steps. Easiest in 8-10.

Comment: 6-7 steps!? This is going to take more than that.

Comment: Totally possible in 6-7.. You may have to get creative or expand beyond a basic US dictionary.. If you stay stricter, it'll take upwards of 10

Comment: what is your definition of a valid word here too? OED?

Comment: Mmmm.. You can get a little creative.. Stretch the OED a bit.. Bring out the scrabble acceptances ;)

Comment: I'm waiting for the first lateral (or ladder-al) answer that tries to change `#0000FF` into `#FFC0CB`.

Comment: If you're okay with sound effects, you could do it in 4! `BLUE` `BLUK` `BIUK` `BINK` `PINK` ;)

Comment: @IanMacDonald I am not entirely sure about that.. but the 6 step I have uses one of those ;)

Comment: @MOehm I think that may take quite a few more steps but creative

Comment: You can do it in five steps, because the low digit of green is already correct. Unless you require that all intermediate colours be valid named HTML colours, too. In that case, good luck!

Comment: @n_palum if we count 'Bink' I can get it down to 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**6 Steps**

> Blue - Flue - Flus - Plus -  Pius - Pins - Pink

Okay, the above had problems as reported by others so I came up with other options with a few scribble word dictionary while some from Merriam.

**6 Steps**

> Blue - Blur - Baur - Bauk - Bank - Bink - Pink

**7 Steps**

> Blue - Blae - Blat - Plat - Peat - Pent - Pint - Pink
>  Blue - Flue - Flus - Feus - Fens - Fins - Fink - Pink
>  Blue - Blae - Blat - Beat - Bent - Bint - Pint - Pink
>  Blue - Flue - Flus - Feus - Fens - Pens - Pins - Pink
>  Blue - Flue - Flus - Feus - Fens - Fins - Pins - Pink

**8 Steps**

> Blue - Flue - Flee - Fled - Feed - Fend - Find - Fink - Pink

**9 Steps**

> Blue - Glue - Glut - Gout - Pout - Port - Part - Pant - Pint - Pink

Comment: uhh.... I think you might have skipped something.

Comment: Pius -> Pink? Thats two changes. You can fix with 'pins' though

Comment: ^ That and Pius is a name

Comment: Pius means saint. Its just a noun not proper noun. http://www.dictionary.com/browse/pius

Comment: No, "pious" means saint. "Pius" (as listed in the link you provided) is a proper name (as listed in the link you provided).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pius I would still argue it is more of a name/formal title - you are saying it is a noun only which I don't think would be right.

Comment: Well, matter of how you treat it. E.g. Bell can be many things. :-)

Comment: @Techidiot Literally every single definition on the page you linked is for a proper name. I don't understand how that's a "matter of how you treat it".

Comment: @Techidiot If one were to treat 'pius' as a noun, then we'd be referring to the *latin* word, which of course is not English

Comment: The one I had was your new 6 step version.. I haven't been able to find anything shorter.. If someone magically pulls out a different answer I'll be impressed but otherwise I'm pretty sure you've got it

Comment: @n_palum Yeah. I tried a lot to pull it down a bit. But, that's what I got. :)

Answer (score 4):

**7 Steps:**

> BLUE FLUE FLUS PLUS POUS PONS PINS PINK
>
>  [A pous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pous) is a Greek unit of measurement.
>
>  [The pons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pons) is part of the brain stem.

Comment: I'm not really sure why my spoiler formatting isn't working. :( Please send help.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling Stack Exchange! I can explain what I did, but you can inspect the changes yourself by clicking [edit]. Spoilers can be tricky to format - you need two spaces at the end to create new lines.

Answer (score 2):

So, shortest, or longest answer wins? (65)

> **blue**
>  clue
>  club
>  chub - A species to fresh-water fish of the Cyprinidae or Carp family
>  chum - A roommate
>  cham - To chew
>  sham
>  spam
>  spar
>  soar
>  boar
>  bear
>  pear
>  peak
>  peck
>  pack
>  park
>  dark
>  dank - Damp; moist; humid; wet
>  dang - imp. of Ding
>  ding
>  ping
>  ring
>  rink - An artificial sheet of ice
>  rank
>  rang - imp. of Ring
>  pang - paroxysm of extreme pain or anguish; to torture
>  pung - A kind of plain sleigh drawn by one horse
>  punt
>  pint
>  pine
>  pike
>  like
>  **lime**
>  limb
>  lamb
>  jamb
>  jams
>  gams
>  gaps
>  gads
>  gods
>  goas
>  goat
>  gout
>  glut
>  glum
>  grum
>  gram
>  **gray**
>  tray
>  tram
>  team
>  **teal**
>  seal
>  sear
>  seer
>  seek
>  peek - To look slyly, or with the eyes half closed
>  peak
>  peck
>  pick
>  puck
>  punk
>  **pink**

Comment: Uhhh I was looking for shortest.. But +1 for the lengthy one

Answer (score 1):

Here's a 10-step.

> **BLUE**, GLUE, GLUM, SLUM, SLIM, SLID, SAID, SAND, SANK, SINK, **PINK**

Answer (score 1):

8 steps:

> **BLUE**, FLUE, FLEE, FLED, FEED, FEND, FIND, FINK, **PINK**

7, if we count 'bink':

> **BLUE**, BLUB, BLOB, BOOB, BOOK, BONK, *BINK*, **PINK**

Comment: Fink is certainly a fun one.. nice